# Jenkins -‘?’ is an unsafe character when creating job

Tags: java, jenkins

I have recently installed a new copy of Jenkins (version 2.1) on my server and I am attempting to create a job. Regardless of what I enter as the job name, it always gives me the same error.

[image]

#### **'?' is an unsafe character**

I haven't been able to create any jobs due to this. And I can't seem to find anything about the issue besides an [unresolved Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12553).

Both letters and numbers are not accepted.

Here is my log file right after trying to create a job:

[image]

I have also tried reinstalling however the issue persists.

Comment: I never ran into that issue. Are you able to provide some log output from Jenkins?

Comment: @Michael See my updated question with the log included.

Comment: Raise the issue on their issue tracker. Uninstall, build from source, reinstall and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Did you check if there's any uncommon locale settings when starting the master?